# Errors while i'm puting my zend framework 2 project online

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm having some trouble puting my **zf2** site online. I upploaded my site to my Godaddy host account and refered my DNS to MY_FOLDER/public .
It's working the redirect but i have a lot of errors that i don't know what i'm doing wrong, can someone help me please?

OBS: in my local project is everything working fine.

this is the URL: http://ceptreinamentos.com.br/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `Admin\Controller\abstractController` should be `Admin\Controller\AbstractController` (note case). You can have this sort of problem if you develop a site on a computer with a case insensitive file system (like Windows), but host it on a server using a case sensitive file system (like Linux).

Comment: Your answer was awesome thank you so much Tim Fountain!